# Gradle Model Rules: How do I create/depend on tasks in model scope

Tags: gradle

I am attempting to use the concepts described in the "Rule based model configuration" docs, and I am having trouble finding a path to do what I need.

I am using the [ruleSourcePluginEach](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/modelRules/ruleSourcePluginEach/build.gradle) sample code to start with, but I need to be able to create a named task and dependOn it somewhere, for each FileItem and/or DirectoryItem.

Basically I need to do something like this:

```
@Managed interface Item extends Named {}
@Managed interface FileItem extends Item {}
@Managed interface DirectoryItem extends Item {
    ModelMap<Item> getChildren()
}

class PluginRules extends RuleSource {
    @Rules void ApplyRulesForDirectory(DirectoryRules rules, @Each DirectoryItem directory)  {}
}
apply plugin: PluginRules

abstract class DirectoryRules extends RuleSource {
    @Mutate
    void CreateTaskForFiles(ModelMap<Task> tasks, ModelMap<FileItem> children) {
        children.each {
            tasks.create(it.name, Task) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}

model {
    root(DirectoryItem) {
        children {
            dir(DirectoryItem) {
                children {
                    file1(FileItem)
                    file2(FileItem)
                }
            }
            file3(FileItem)
        }
    }
}
```

However, running this in gradle 3.3 fails with:

```
The following model rules could not be applied due to unbound inputs and/or subjects:

DirectoryRules#CreateTaskForFiles(ModelMap<Task>, ModelMap<FileItem>)
  subject:
    - <no path> ModelMap<Task> (parameter 1) [*]
        scope: root
  inputs:
    - <no path> ModelMap<FileItem> (parameter 2) [*]

[*] - indicates that a model item could not be found for the path or type.
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Cheers and thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my limited knowledge of Gradle's rule-based model can tell, there are 2 problems with your configuration:

1. Since the `DirectoryRules` rules are applied with *scope* (i.e. not applied to the root of the model as a plugin), you need to give it all model elements it needs access to. You haven't given it the `ModelMap<Task> tasks`, so that's the first problem. A potential solution would be:

   ```
   class PluginRules extends RuleSource {
       @Rules
       void ApplyRulesForDirectory(DirectoryRules rules,
               ModelMap<Task> tasks, @Each DirectoryItem directory)  {}
   }
   ```

   However, that reveals the second problem...
2. It looks like Gradle's `@Each` annotation can only be used on the *target* of a rule (i.e. the thing being modified), whereas you're trying to use it on one of the rule's *inputs* (the target is the `ModelMap<Task> tasks`). I don't know why this restriction is applied to `@Each`; presumably it's to do with when/how matching model objects are detected.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to suggest an ideal or idiomatic solution. However, naively, this seems to work:

```
@Managed interface Item extends Named {}
@Managed interface FileItem extends Item {}
@Managed interface DirectoryItem extends Item {
    ModelMap<Item> getChildren()
}

class PluginRules extends RuleSource {
    @Mutate
    void CreateTasksForFiles(ModelMap<Task> tasks, @Path("root") DirectoryItem directory) {
        directory.children.withType(FileItem).each {
            tasks.create(it.name, Task) {
                // ...
            }
        }
        directory.children.withType(DirectoryItem).each {
            ApplyRulesForDirectory(tasks, it)
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: PluginRules

model {
    root(DirectoryItem) {
        children {
            dir(DirectoryItem) {
                children {
                    file1(FileItem)
                    file2(FileItem)
                }
            }
            file3(FileItem)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I get it. I just need to inject the path from the rood node, and operate accordingly on the child nodes. I did run into the same issue you RE @each with model inputs. This looks to be an acceptable work around though.